# Change generateseries order in Dax

Tags: dax, generate-series

I have this dax code

var ....

Return

UNION(ROW(Value,1), Row(Value,2),
GENERATESERIES( Last5Years, SelectedYear, 1) ,
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Season Code))

[image: That create this table Name 2018 2019 2020 2021 2022 A 1 8 8 5 3 B 2 6 2 3 5 C 3 3 3 4 6]

but user want the table by Year descending, like this

[image]

Which dax function i need to do to change the order of the series

Thanks so much for your help

Javier

Answer (score 1):

The GENERATESERIES does not accept a negative step, therefore a workaround shuld be used, like for instance

```
SELECTCOLUMNS( GENERATESERIES( -1 * SelectedYear, -1 * Last5Years, 1), "Value", -1 * [Value] )
```

[Here is an example in dax.do](https://dax.do/1B81jJaEdmgNKF/)

Comment: Hi Sergio thanks so much for your help but doesn't work  When I move to columns

Comment: Then I'm afraid that the problem is not the order of the generated series, but the way it's shown in the visual. I'm afraid that the only option is to use the Order By property for the column with the year like explained here https://www.biinsight.com/quick-tips-how-to-sort-matrix-by-column-in-descending-order/

Answer (score 0):

RANKX(
filter (
all ('Measures'),
'Measures[Category] = "Year" ),
'Measures'[Value],,DESC,DENSE)

if ( 'Measures '[Category] <> "Year" ||   Len ([Value]) > 4 ,

```
                if ( 'Measures'[Value] <= MaxSeason 
                    && 'Measures'[Value] >= PrevYearSeasonCode , 
                    SeasonRank &"@"& 'Measures '[Value] ),
```